Heat equation with a Spherical heat conduction, optical spot welding related
In the paper I need to discuss a heat transfer problem, such as the heat transfer phenomenon of laser welding a smooth planar component with a spot radius of r0. I simplify it into half of the heat transfer near a small spherical space that generates heat. The conduction power of the spherical heat transfer boundary with radius r0 is constant at W. Assuming that the heat transfer process occurs in the space where r0<r<R, R is large enough, you can also consider it as infinite. I simplify it into the following differential equation. I know that the characteristic function method is applicable in one-dimensional situations, but this does make it difficult for me to handle.
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = \frac{K}{C_v\rho} \ \nabla^2 u,\ r_0<|\mathbf{r}|<R
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
u|_{t=0} = T_0 
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
u|_{r=R} = T_0, \\
\nabla u|_{r=r_0}= \frac{W}{4\pi r_0^2 K}\hat{\mathbf{r}},  
  \ \hat{\mathbf{r}}=\frac{\mathbf{r}}{|\mathbf{r}|}
\end{equation}
In the equations, K is the heat transfer rate and Cv is the specific heat capacity,The most important thing is that I hope to find out how fast the temperature rises near the r0 boundary. I hope my physical to mathematical conversion should be relatively correct, but I am not proficient in mathematical methods.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Does anyone have any suggestions for the transformation of this physics problem
